# How can I compare two values in angularjs in HTMl

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope, angularjs-ng-repeat

How can I compare two scope values using angularjs in HTML only?

for example:

```
<div ng-if="place.id = place.reference.id"> show if equals</div>
```

I want this to cover certain scanrios

Comment: use `==`, it is the condition operator. `=` is for assignment

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are assigning something this way...

To check for equality you need == or ===, but 3 should be used as Doug says -

> "If there is every anything that causes unwanted effects and can be
>   solved by something else, use the something else..."

Ok maybe he didnt say that exactly but you get the point....

```
<div ng-if="place.id === place.reference.id"> show if equals</div>
```